# SELECT TOP N WITH TIES @scalar_value = count(*)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to set scalar value. Needed result is from `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` block. How can I do it properly?

The way how I am trying to do, is:

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
CREATE FUNCTION funcGetLastFridayOrders
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @orders_quantity SMALLINT
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES @orders_quantity = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
    WHERE DATEPART(DAY,OrderDate) = 5
    GROUP BY OrderDate 
    ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
    RETURN @order_quantity
END
```

Error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@order_quantity"

Whereas

```
DECLARE @var INT
SELECT @var = intValue FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

works fine.

Comment: You want `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, which explicitly opens up the possibility of the query returning more than one row, but then you're assigning that result to a scalar variable? I cannot comprehend what the thought process would be that would reach this particular point.

Comment: I'm counting orders made last friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error

`DECLARE @orders_quantity SMALLINT`

but you use in return

```
RETURN @order_quantity
```

Comment: Thank you. I promise to be more attentive!

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo in the return line. You wrote "order_quantity" instead of "orders_quantity".

This is the corrected statement:

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
CREATE FUNCTION funcGetLastFridayOrders
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @orders_quantity SMALLINT
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES @orders_quantity = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
    WHERE DATEPART(DAY,OrderDate) = 5
    GROUP BY OrderDate 
    ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
    RETURN @orders_quantity
END
```